# How could I train one model which forecast multiple groups? (Time Series Problem)

Tags: machine-learning, python, forecasting

Firstly, I would like to apologize if if this is question has been discuss. I am pretty new to TS Forecasting.

I have a question about how to approach time series problem. I have a data set that has columns for date, store identifier, employee identifier, number of employees, sales, hours worked, holidays, etc. My main question is how to transform the dataset to forecast sales per employee for the following month using the information of more dimensions besides sales.

to be more specific in order to make this question more answerable. let's say I have a dataset with this shape

| date | employee_id | worked hrs | holiday hrs | ... | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 160 | 0 | ... | 10000 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | 148 | 12 | ... | 8000 |
| 2020-01-01 | 3 | 60 | 100 | ... | 15000 |
| 2020-02-01 | 1 | 178 | 0 | ... | 9500 |
| 2020-02-01 | 2 | 165 | 5 | ... | 1000 |
| 2020-02-01 | 3 | 180 | 0 | ... | 30000 |
| 2020-03-01 | 1 | 140 | 20 | ... | 11000 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

My goal will be to create a model to forecast the number of sales for each employee for next month, so if my train set last until June, my goal will be to forecast July sales and feed my model with new data the next month and so on.

The thing is that, for all documentation and kernels I have found, the forecasting was done either grouping all sales together or creating N models per employee (being N the number of employees)

How could I, if possible, just train ONE model which forecast the next month sales per employee?

In addition I would also like to try different models, from Logistic Regression, SArima, prophet to random forest Xboost etc. I understand that I will have to do different transformations for the different models. For example I don't think I can use the rest of the dimensions in sarima or Prophet, but I'm not sure either.

Moreover, I would like to cover the basics before get into Deep Learning frameworks

I am very sorry if this is question has been discuss

Any help or documentation is appreciate

Comment: It looks like you have some good questions to ask, but they need more focus to be answerable here.  Please take a look at our [help] for more information -- and welcome to CV.

Comment: There are considerations not mentioned. For example, how many hours is a store opened, months do not have equal numbers of weekdays, holidays, and we don't have information about store hours, and when they occur. There may be sales differences for each day of the week, and so forth. Without more exact information sales patterns for each employee will contain more uncertainty than they should.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am not looking for a specific  answer to my problem, I am looking for a more maybe theoretical way o documentation of who approach this problem of hierarchical time series forecasting and learn from that how to model my dataset to fit the model, how to debug the model, how to evaluate it. This kind of things